# TypeError: Column is not iterable - Using map() and explode() in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
 Row(name='Angel', age=5, height=None,weight=40,desc = "Where is Angel"),
 Row(name='Bobby', age=None, height=40,weight=50,desc = "This is Bobby")
]).toDF()

df.select(map(col("desc"), col("age")).alias("complex_map"))\
  .selectExpr("explode(complex_map)").show(2)
```

**while running the above code geting an error :**
***TypeError: Column is not iterable***

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `create_map` function, not the native Python `map`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.select(F.create_map(F.col("desc"), F.col("age")).alias("complex_map"))\
  .selectExpr("explode(complex_map)").show(2)
```

To simplify the code further,

```
df.select(
    F.explode(
        F.create_map(F.col("desc"), F.col("age"))
    ).alias("complex_map")
).show(2)
```